# Custom Boom error messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

On my Hapi.js server, I'd like to send a specific message if an account does not have permission rights to access an api endpoint. The Boom message I have right now looks like this:

```
return reply(Boom.unauthorized("unauthorized access to this API."));
```

This returns a message that looks like this:

```
{
  "statusCode": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "unauthorized access to this API."
}
```

I would like to make it more customized to look like this:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "unauthorized access to this API.",
  "csrf-decorator": "",
  "redirect": ""
}
```

Do we have access to customize the Boom error messages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boom comes with built in response [error transformation](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#error-transformation). So in order to achieve my results I had reformat my error reply in the following way:

```
const error = Boom.forbidden("Sorry, you are restricted in accesssing this API. No soup for you!.");
error.output.statusCode = 403;    // Assign a custom error code
error.output.payload["csrf-decorator"] = request.headers["csrf-decorator"];
error.reformat();
return reply(error);
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Hapijs documentation](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#error-transformation) you can reformat error messages to customize them:

#### Error transformation

Errors can be customized by changing their output content. The boom error object includes the following properties:

- isBoom - if true, indicates this is a Boom object instance.
- message - the error message.
- output - the formatted response. Can be directly manipulated after object construction to return a custom error response. Allowed root keys:
- statusCode - the HTTP status code (typically 4xx or 5xx).

  - headers - an object containing any HTTP headers where each key is a    header name and value is the header content.
  - payload - the formatted object used as the response payload    (stringified). Can be directly manipulated but any changes will be    lost if reformat() is called. Any content allowed and by default    includes the following content:

    - statusCode - the HTTP status code, derived from
      error.output.statusCode.
    - error - the HTTP status message (e.g. 'Bad Request', 'Internal Server
      Error') derived from statusCode.
    - message - the error message derived from error.message.
- inherited Error properties.

It also supports the following method:

- reformat() - rebuilds error.output using the other object properties.

```js
const Boom = require('boom');

const handler = function (request, h) {
    const error = Boom.badRequest('Cannot feed after midnight');
    error.output.statusCode = 499;    // Assign a custom error code
    error.reformat();
    error.output.payload.custom = 'abc_123'; // Add custom key
    throw error;
});
```

When a different error representation is desired, such as an HTML page or a different payload format, the `onPreResponse` extension point may be used to identify errors and replace them with a different response object.

```js
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Vision = require('vision');

const server = Hapi.server({ port: 80 });
server.register(Vision, (err) => {
    server.views({
        engines: {
            html: require('handlebars')
        }
    });
});

const preResponse = function (request, h) {

    const response = request.response;
    if (!response.isBoom) {
        return h.continue;
    }

    // Replace error with friendly HTML

      const error = response;
      const ctx = {
          message: (error.output.statusCode === 404 ? 'page not found' : 'something went wrong')
      };

      return h.view('error', ctx).code(error.output.statusCode);
};

server.ext('onPreResponse', preResponse);
```